# How to call a function and load part of view using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to hide a div and load another div by calling a function in ajax, but it's not redirecting me to that function.I just want to load a div without refreshing the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkVoucher(){
var voucher_number = $("#voucher_number").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('cart/gift_validate'); ?>",
    data: {gift_voucher_number:voucher_number} , 

    success: function(data){
        $('#gift_msg').html('<span id="gift_msg" style="display:block;">'+data+'</span>');
        $('.order_details').html('').hide();
        $('.cart_table').html('');
        $('.cart_table').load('cart/ajax_cart_view');
        return false;
    },
});
}

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function ajax_cart_view()
{   
    $gift_data = $this->cart_model->getgiftvoucher();
    if($gift_data){
        $this->data['giftDiscount'] = $giftData['amount'];
        $this->data['giftID']       = $giftData['id'];
    }
    $this->load->view('cart/ajax_cart',$this->data);
}
```

View :(Contains div which needs to be loaded on the same page)

```
<div class="order_details_ajax">
.
 .
</div>
```

Comment: I have called it onclick sir

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the success method is deprecated.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Pass it a .done() after you close your parentheses:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo base_url('cart/gift_validate'); ?>",
data: {gift_voucher_number:voucher_number} , 
}).done(
 function(data){
    $('#gift_msg').html('<span id="gift_msg" style="display:block;">'+data+'</span>');
    $('.order_details').html('').hide();
    $('.cart_table').html('');
    $('.cart_table').load('cart/ajax_cart_view');
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax call with following, because there is mistake in your success function :-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('cart/gift_validate'); ?>",
    data: {gift_voucher_number:voucher_number} , 

    success: function(data){
        $('.order_details_ajax').html('<span id="gift_msg" style="display:block;">'+data+'</span>');
        $('.order_details').html('').hide();
        $('.cart_table').html('');
        $('.cart_table').load('cart/ajax_cart_view');
        return false;
    },
});
}
```